# Declare and initialize a character array separately in C language

Tags: arrays, c, authentication, codeblocks

Hi I am trying to make a simple login system with C with the use of character array and this is my first step. I want to separately declare and initialize a character array and I don't know how to do it correctly but I try to make a code, but I receive a warning. `warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast`. I am using CodeBlocks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char username[25];
  char password[25];

  username[25] = "pyromagne";
  password[25] = "qwerty";

  // char username[25] = "pyromagne"; THIS TWO WORKS DECLARED AND INTITIALIZED TOGETHER
  // char password[25] = "qwerty";

  /* IGNORE THIS, But if there is wrong to this that can produce errors in the future please correct me thanks.
  printf("enter username: ");
  scanf("%s", username);

  printf("enter your password: ");
  scanf("%s", password);
  */

  getch();

  printf("%s\n", username);
  printf("%s\n", password);


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `username` is an array of 25 characters, so `username[25]` is a single character and outside the bounds of the original array. You can't assign to an array so you'll need to use something like `strcpy` to copy the data into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign string literals to a mutable character array. You can change it to:

```
char *username = "pyromagne";
char *password = "qwerty";
```

Or if you will want to change these strings later:

```
char username[25];
char password[25];
strncpy(username, "pyromagne", sizeof(username) - 1);
strncpy(password, "qwerty", sizeof(password) - 1);
```

Comment: Is `strncpy` available in C?

Comment: Yes. Just use `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Wow that functions is useful thanks for the information.

Comment: The difference between `strcpy` and `strncpy` is that `strcpy` will only write to the array up to the terminating null character, and will leave the rest of the array uninitialized, whereas `strncpy` will set the rest of the array to zero, which would also have happened if the array had been initialized in the declaration. In this case, it is probably sufficient to use `strcpy`. However, when dealing with passwords, it can be useful to zero out the entire array.

Comment: This is bad use of `strncpy`, it will not null-terminate if the buffer is too small, leading  to a later buffer overflow error . You can use `strlcpy` or `snprintf`

Comment: @M.M the `strlcpy` is also belong to the `<string.h>` header right?